# How to create an IOS app link for call to action button on a facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I need to add an app link for call to action button on a facebook page but it always show the invalid link error message like and image below.

(I have tried http://jarbstudio.com/babai/, ://jarbstudio.com/babai/, jarbstudio.com/babai/ but all of it seems error)

[image]

How can i fix this? thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this belongs on StackOverflow, but from what i can find on facebook's own help discussions, there seems to be a bug in that form. some users report it working without using `http://` in front of your url, (just using `www.jarbstudio.com/babai`) and others claim that they don't seem to run into the bug when using firefox.

Comment: you might also want to click the 'learn more' link and see what it says.

Comment: You probably want to use a link to the iOS App Store page for your app